# Scrolling not smooth with ScrollView control in IOS devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, skiasharp

I have been using SkiaSharp for a few month now and having great success on showing my drawing instructions on Android & IOS device.  I am using SKCanvasView control which I am placing it inside ScrollView control. On scroll of ScrollView translating SKCanvasView to ScrollTop and ScrollLeft position so that SKCanvasView should intact with Visible region of ScrollView Control.

This is all working smoothly in Android. But in IOS device, scrolling is not smooth. Scrolling is holding by UI thread and it si not smooth. PLease have a look at the code and please suggest if you have any suggestions.

```
    private void View_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        SKRect rect = paginatedViewProvider.GetViewPortRect();

        // I have lots of image tiles which I am drawing on skbitmap and returning it. This is taking around 10ms
        SKBitmap pageBitmap = GenerateSKBitmapFromIntenseCalculation();

        float Top = (float)(rect.Top - scrollTop);
        float Left = (float)(rect.Left - scrollLeft);

        e.Surface.Canvas.DrawBitmap(pageBitmap, SKRect.Create(Left, Top, rect.Width, rect.Height));
    }

    private bool OnTimerTick()
    {
        viewPanel.InvalidateSurface();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Well, like your method "GenerateSKBitmapFromIntenseCalculation" lets it think, you seem to be doing heavy calculation on the UI thread ?! Scrolling is done by the UI Thread so ... Have you tried making your calculations on another thread, and only calling e.Surface.Canvas.DrawBitmap on the UI Thread ?

Comment: This is definitely be a good solutions but I am unable to make SKBitmap thread safe. If I spawn a thread to process "GenerateSKBitmapFromIntenseCalculation" and UI thread should check if task has been completed and it should pick the updated SKBitmap and draw. How to share SKBitmap between UI thread and background thread.

Comment: You could use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` when your calculations are done and the canvas is ready.

Comment: I think to draw onto the canvas I have to register "PaintSurface" event. Inside this event I have to draw so I don't think "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread" will help me in this case.

Comment: Maybe you can try create a background thread and use [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) to wait creating SKBitmap finished and then DrawBitmap.